# How do I pass a reference to $http in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following controller definition:

```
angular.module('myapp', [ 'ngRoute' ]).config(function($routeProvider,
$httpProvider) {

[...]
})
.controller('edit', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $scope.projectid = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.viewer = "undefined";
    $scope.mode = 'nothing';
    var projectid = $routeParams.id;
})
.directive('initCesium', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (typeof Cesium !== "undefined") {
                startup(Cesium, scope);
            } else if (typeof require === "function") {
                require(["Cesium", "scope"], startup);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I need to send a web service request in function `startup`. Therefore I need to pass `$http` to `startup` in 2 places:

1. `startup(Cesium, scope);`
2. `require(["Cesium", "scope"], startup);`

How can I do that?

Comment: And `startup` is?...

Comment: how about `.directive('initCesium', function($http){ ... `  and then `startup(Cesium, scope, $http)`  or simply `angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$http')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok its straight and simple.

Below is the working code i have created that illustrates how **$http** object can be accessed in the **link** function of your directive.

> In your case you can apply the below logic to pass references to the
>   functions you intend to access $http object.

Checkout the Js fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/s5tx7mwr/2/)

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('components', [])

    app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope","$http", function($scope, $http){        
        $scope.ctrl = "Works!"
        $scope.http = $http;
    }]);
    app.directive('helloWorld', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EC',            
            link:function(scope, elemnt, attrs){
                console.log("Directive");                                                        
                scope.http.post("/echo/json/", "json=%7B%22name%22%3A%22nirus%22%7D")
                .success(function(data, status) {
                    scope.name = data.name;
                   console.log(data.name)
                }).error(function (status) {
                    console.log("Error occured")
                });
            },            
            template: '<span>Hello {{name}} : it {{ctrl}}</span>'
        }
    })

angular.module('HelloApp', ['components'])
```

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html ng-app="HelloApp">
   <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <hello-world></hello-world>
   </body>
  </html>
```

In my link function i am able to access the http object.

**Hope this helps you!**